# Flutter Container transform (animation package)

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

randomly when i seeing flutter packages and libraries, i found out `animations` [package](https://github.com/flutter/packages) of flutter and into that i see, there is one of my very useful animation like with android `Gmail` application which that have search navigation animation. to understand what i mean you can see [this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/packages/master/packages/animations/example/demo_gifs/container_transform_lineup.gif), number 4 animation

i looked at source folder of this package in repository on github, but i can't find sample implementation of this animation and i'm not sure that have sample code, is any body help me how can use `Container transform` to have that?

Comment: Have you tried any code?
If Yes, then please mention here so that it is easy to answer your question.

Comment: @RonakPatel no, i can't find any good documentation and sample code to implementing that

Comment: please check hero animations in flutter, you can even implement the feature using `AnimatedContainer`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Animations package provides [OpenContainer](https://pub.dev/documentation/animations/latest/animations/OpenContainer-class.html) widget.

This widget has 2 builders: `openBuilder`  `closedBuilder`.
**ClosedBuilder** returns the widget that user sees before open and after close widget, in flowing example it is `SearchBar`.
**OpenBuilder** returns the page showing after user opens the closed widget, in flowing example it is `SearchPage`.

open and close actions trigger by calling callback: `openContainer`, `closeContainer`.

[image]

```
import 'package:animations/animations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String searchString;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: OpenContainer<String>(
            openBuilder: (_, closeContainer) => SearchPage(closeContainer),
            onClosed: (res) => setState(() {
              searchString = res;
            }),
            tappable: false,
            closedBuilder: (_, openContainer) => SearchBar(
              searchString: searchString,
              openContainer: openContainer,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchBar(
      {Key key, @required this.searchString, @required this.openContainer})
      : super(key: key);

  final String searchString;
  final VoidCallback openContainer;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 3,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: openContainer,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.search),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              searchString != null
                  ? Expanded(child: Text(searchString))
                  : Spacer(),
              Icon(Icons.mic),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchPage(
    this.onClose, {
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final void Function({String returnValue}) onClose;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                    spreadRadius: 0,
                    blurRadius: 1,
                    color: Colors.black26,
                  )
                ],
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                    onPressed: onClose,
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Icon(Icons.mic),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  OutlineButton(
                    onPressed: () => onClose(returnValue: 'Flutter'),
                    child: Text('Search: "Flutter"'),
                  ),
                  OutlineButton(
                    onPressed: () => onClose(returnValue: 'Rabbit'),
                    child: Text('Search: "Rabbit"'),
                  ),
                  OutlineButton(
                    onPressed: () => onClose(returnValue: 'What is the Matrix'),
                    child: Text('Search: "What is the Matrix"'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to get response data from SecondScreen Navigator.of(context).pop(data) ? I try to use onClosed: (data) {} but it always return null

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I am wrong, but aren't these two the same animation?

#1[image: gif of what OP is looking for] #2[image: gif of what is already present in the example lib]

Gif #1 is what you said you are looking for. Gif #2 is what I got by following the example without making any meaningful changes:
https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/master/packages/animations/example/lib

Take a closer look at `container_transition.dart`, specifically what `_ExampleCard` returns. I won't be pasting any code here because: 1) In case the package changes I advise future readers to take a look at the official examples rather than blindly copy pasting from my answer which might become obsolete; 2) You didn't bother to post any yourself.

Comment: i checked your link, it isn't what i want to have, do you have simple sample code?